# Does Git server over SSH requires SFTP?

Tags: ssh, git, sftp

Does Git server over SSH requires SFTP module? Official manual lacks info here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. Git over ssh works by launching the git-upload-pack command via SSH. It does not copy files like sftp/scp do.

Comment: So to make it work through /usr/bin/git-shell you have to allow the access to command `git-upload-pack` in git-shell settings?

Comment: Yes. And git-receive-pack if push needs to work too :)